# Keys to Mongoose Object are different from property names

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In order to troubleshoot an error I have been getting, I wrote the following snippet:

```
var myFunction = function(obj) {
var keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj);
console.log(obj);
console.log(keys);
}
```

When running my function within a mongoose query callback, the console logs this:

```
{_id: 5a8g123vjsdj83nf8afvn48,
username: 'Player1',
adv1: { name: 'a', type: '!' },
adv2: { name: 'a', type: '!' },
adv3: { name: 'a', type: '!' },
__v: 0,
invitations: [ 'PlayTest1', 'PlayTest2' ] }

[ '$__', 'isNew', 'errors', '_doc', '$init' ]
```

Now as far as I understand it, the last line in the console (separated for reading convenience) should read:

```
[ '_id', 'username', 'adv1', 'adv2', 'adv3', '__v', 'invitations ]
```

My question is why does the keys obj I create in myFunction not contain the properties names shown when I log the actual object?

Comment: The document fields are stored in `obj._doc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoose document fields are stored in [`obj._doc`](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/document.js#L67)

`console.log` displays the document fields due to an [`.inspect`](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/document.js#L2373-L2383) function attached to the document object.

Use `node --inspect` if you want to debug something.